# How to fix leak in toilet?

Tags: leak, toilet

[image]

I’ve had this leak in my toilet for almost 2 years, I decided to try and fix the problem myself by using some waterproof silicone, but I’m worried I ended up messing something up and might have to start over. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Where is/was the leak coming from?  From the joint at the tank or where the nut screws onto the threads?

Comment: @crip659 click to zoom the image and you can see a drop of water at the top.

Answer (score 2):

So, that's the fill valve. You shut off the water, drain and sponge out the tank, remove the valve, check VERY carefully for tank cracks, if no tank cracks, clean the surfaces very well & install a new rubber washer and tighten it without over-tightening it (that perhaps counter-intuitively, often causes leaks. If massively overdone it can also cause cracks.)

If the tank is cracked you need a new tank, or a new toilet. I suppose you could try caulking, but I would not expect success, and I'd also expect an eventual catastrophic failure when the crack grows some more and eventially the tank splits open.

Usually it's just in need of the washer.